# Como sumar y agrupar elementos de un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, sum

tengo un array como el siguiente, el cual deseo agrupar por id y parametro sumando los totales validos correspondientes es decir, sería como lo siguiente:

Este es mi array actual:

```
[{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6}
{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6}
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6}
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 4}
{id: 2, parametro: 'verde', totales_validos: 0}]
```

Lo que necesito es que me devuelva algo como lo siguiente:

```
[{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 12}
 {id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 10}
 {id: 2, parametro: 'verde', totales_validos: 0}]
```

Hasta el momento he logrado agruparla por id.

var array = response.data.groupwithcount;

```
var miarray = [];

$.each(array,function(index,element){
  if(miarray[element.centro]==undefined){
      miarray[element.centro] =0;
  }
  miarray[element.centro] += element.totales_validos;
});
console.log(miarray);
```

Esto arroja

```
 [empty, 2, 3]
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? ¿O pretendes que otro lo haga por ti?

Comment: listo, lo agregue

Comment: Muy bien, tienes mi +1, además trataré de darte una respuesta (en cuanto pueda). Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Una posibiliadad podría ser usando `.reduce` guardando la combinación `c.id+c.parametro` en el acumulador, si es que buscamos las combinaciones distíntas de `.id` y `.parametro`.

```js
const obj = [{id: 1,parametro: 'rojo',totales_validos: 6},{id: 1,parametro: 'rojo',totales_validos: 6},{id: 2,parametro: 'rojo',totales_validos: 6},{id: 2,parametro:'rojo',totales_validos: 4},{id: 2,parametro: 'verde',totales_validos: 0}];


const res = obj.reduce((p, c) => {

  let idx = p[0].indexOf(c.id + c.parametro);

  if (idx > -1) {

    p[1][idx].totales_validos += c.totales_validos

  } else {

    p[0].push(c.id + c.parametro);
    p[1].push(c);
  }

  return p;

}, [[],[]]);

console.log(res[1]);
```

En el acumulador del `.reduce` pasamos `[[],[]]`, en la primera posicion insertamos las distintas combinaciones, en la segunda el objeto completo, sumando los valores.

Comment: y en el caso que mi array venga de un response de ajax, deberia mantener lo mismo? estoy teniendo un leve error de sumas al recibirlo como const array = response.data.group;

Comment: Si, debería ser lo mismo si el array tiene la misma estructura. Quiźa los números son strings. Si ese fuera el caso hay que castear los valores como numeros. Puede ser haciendo `c.totales_validos = +c.totales_validos;`

Answer (score 0):

Presento una solución genérica, para agrupar cualquier lista de objetos. Para los que conozcan `Linq` su uso le resultará familiar.

Advierto que no es la más eficiente, porque siempre será más eficiente atender al caso particular. Pero es una solución viable para muchos casos de usos, cuando se requiere usar la agrupación sobre objetos distintos varias veces, como por ejemplo acomodar datos para la representación de un gráfico.

**1.- Suma de un array**

Parto con una función que suma el contenido de una array

```js
Array.prototype.Sum = function (exp = null) {
    if (exp == null)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += i, 0);
    else if (exp instanceof Function)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += exp(i), 0);
    else
        return this.reduce(a => a += exp, 0);
}

//=================================
//Ejemplos

const ej1 = [{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 4},
{id: 2, parametro: 'verde', totales_validos: 0}];

const ej2 = [1,2,3,4];

console.log( ej1.Sum(a=>a.totales_validos) ); //sumamos según el atributo totales_validos
console.log( ej1.Sum(a=>a.id) ); //sumamos según el atributo id

console.log( ej2.Sum() ); //sumamos un array de números

console.log( ej1.Sum(10) ); //sumamos una constante n veces, siendo n el largo del array
```

**2.- Groupby**

Es necesario tener la claridad de que el resultado esperado de una agrupación debería dar un `array de array's`

```js
Array.prototype.GroupBy = function(exp) {
    return  Object.values( this.reduce((acc, i) => {
        acc[exp(i)] ? acc[exp(i)].push(i) : acc[exp(i)] = [i];
        return acc;
    }, {}));
}
//=================================
//Ejemplos

const ej1 = [{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 4},
{id: 2, parametro: 'verde', totales_validos: 0}];


console.log( ej1.GroupBy(a=>a.parametro) ); //Agrupar por el atributo totales_validos
console.log( ej1.GroupBy(a=>a.id) ); //Agrupar por el atributo id

console.log( ej1.GroupBy(a=> [a.id, a.parametro] ) ); //Agrupar por ambos atributos
```

**3.- Modo de uso**

```js
Array.prototype.Sum = function (exp = null) {
    if (exp == null)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += i, 0);
    else if (exp instanceof Function)
        return this.reduce((a, i) => a += exp(i), 0);
    else
        return this.reduce(a => a += exp, 0);
}

Array.prototype.GroupBy = function(exp) {
    return  Object.values( this.reduce((acc, i) => {
        acc[exp(i)] ? acc[exp(i)].push(i) : acc[exp(i)] = [i];
        return acc;
    }, {}));
}

const ej1 = [{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 1, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 6},
{id: 2, parametro: 'rojo', totales_validos: 4},
{id: 2, parametro: 'verde', totales_validos: 0}];



const resultado = ej1.GroupBy(a=>[a.id,a.parametro]).map(a=> ({
                       id : a[0].id,
                       parametro : a[0].parametro,
                       totales_validos : a.Sum(b=>b.totales_validos)
                     }));
                     
console.log(resultado);
```

Primero agrupamos el array, que nos dará el array de array's. Luego usando un `map` seleccionamos el primer `id` y `parametro` que siempre estarán repetidos para todos los elementos (ya que agrupamos por ellos) y luego sumamos el atributo `totales_validos`