# Como sumar y agrupar elementos en un array resultante en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, find, reduce

tengo el siguiente Array:

```
arr1 = [
    { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 1200 },
    { paddockTypeId: 4, area: 500 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 20000 },
    { paddockTypeId: 3, area: 8401 },
    { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 2877 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 15902 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 1736 },
    { paddockTypeId: 3, area: 2965 },
    { paddockTypeId: 4, area: 1651 },
    { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 700 },
    { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 7956 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 3745 },
    { paddockTypeId: 3, area: 11362 },
    { paddockTypeId: 3, area: 300 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 19188 },
    { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 17137 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 100 },
    { paddockTypeId: 3, area: 11845 },
    { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 15969 },
    { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 10420 },
    { paddockTypeId: 3, area: 3200 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 10587 },
    { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 16750 }
];
```

como podria crear una funcion para sumar los totales de area de cada paddockTypeId y despues colocarlos en un nuevo array, teniendo como resultado lo siguiente:

```
[
   { paddockTypeId: 1, area: 56259},
   { paddockTypeId: 2, area: 88088},
   { paddockTypeId: 3, area: 38073 },
   { paddockTypeId: 4, area: 2151},
]
```

tenia pensado un find con un reduce, pero la verdad despues de intentarlo no logro encontrar el resultado.

Gracias =).

Comment: [Otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/483219/169744). Esta aparece en publicaciones relacionadas a tu pregunta. Bienvenido y busca bien antes de preguntar para que tus preguntas no sean cerradas. Aunque no fuese un duplicado, [es importante investigar antes de preguntar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/169744). En el [centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask) también está.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer así:

```js
const arr1 = [{
    paddockTypeId: 1,
    area: 1200
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 4,
    area: 500
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 20000
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 3,
    area: 8401
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 1,
    area: 2877
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 15902
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 1736
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 3,
    area: 2965
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 4,
    area: 1651
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 1,
    area: 700
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 1,
    area: 7956
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 3745
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 3,
    area: 11362
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 3,
    area: 300
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 19188
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 1,
    area: 17137
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 100
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 3,
    area: 11845
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 1,
    area: 15969
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 1,
    area: 10420
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 3,
    area: 3200
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 10587
  },
  {
    paddockTypeId: 2,
    area: 16750
  }
];

//Usamos object values para solo obtener sus valores (eliminando las keys que creamos en el reduce)
const result = Object.values(arr1.reduce((acc, e) => {
  //En el acumulador, si el elemento no existe, lo creas y lo inicializas. El elemento se crea como una clave/valor, para poder hacer mas facil su busqueda.
  acc[e.paddockTypeId] = acc[e.paddockTypeId] || {
    paddockTypeId: e.paddockTypeId,
    area: 0
  };
  //Una vez creado sumas el area con el valor que ya tenga
  acc[e.paddockTypeId].area += e.area;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera como mencionaste es haciendo uso del método .reduce()

```
arr1.reduce( (acumuladores, nuevo) => { 
    const buscado = acumuladores.find( c => c.paddockTypeId === nuevo.paddockTypeId );

    //Chequeamos si ya se encuentra el valor a 'acumular'
    if( buscado ) { 

        //Si ya existe incrementamos el acumulador actual
        buscado.area += nuevo.area
    } else {

        //En caso contrario lo agregamos.
        acumuladores.push(nuevo)
    } return acumuladores;
}, []) //Hacemos uso de un array vació para agrupar los acumuladores.
```